# Swift + Not Deleting Current Item in Single Linked List

Tags: swift, algorithm, linked-list

I have a linked list that is not deleting the current item based off the inserted value which in the case below is the value of 5.0. I want to delete 5.0 from my inserted values but the console is still printing out all inserted values of 5.0, 8.0, and 10.0. I tried changing the conditions in func delete() and tried several changes in the block of code that is executed in func delete() as well. I suspect something is backwards with `head?.nextNodeAddress = head?.nextNodeAddress` inside func delete(). Also, does the current value actually get deleted in a linked list when setting head (e.g. pointer) to the next node address or does it just overlook the current node value that matches the inserted value?

Note: I did not include func insert(value:) because it did not seem to pertain to the issue. The value insert as expected.

//Node Class:

```
class Node {
    
    let value: Double
    var nextNodeAddress: Node?
    
    init(value: Double, next: Node?) {
        self.value = value
        self.nextNodeAddress = next
    }
}
```

//Linked List

```
class LinkedList {
    
    var head: Node?
    
    func delete(value: Double) {
        if head?.value != value {
            head?.nextNodeAddress = head?.nextNodeAddress
        }
    }
    
    
    func displayListItems() {
        
        var current = head
        while current != nil {
            print(current?.value ?? "")
            current = current?.nextNodeAddress
        }
    }

}

let boltSize = LinkedList()
boltSize.insert(value: 5.0)
boltSize.insert(value: 8.0)
boltSize.insert(value: 10.0)
boltSize.delete(value: 5.0)
boltSize.displayListItems()
```

Comment: It's probably a good idea to add your insert method so we can verify there aren't any bugs. It will also help us understand your algorithm. To answer one of your questions, if you delete a node in the middle of the list, the previous node should point to the node after the deleted node. Also, the item you are deleting is the head, you have to replace the head. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

As Rob stated above, it's best to add your insert function as well so that we can rule out any bugs in the insert.

However, I does not seem like the delete function does anything.

Let's trace it.

After your three inserts your linked list looks like this assuming your insert works fine.

`node(5.0) -> node(8.0) -> node(10.0)` and `Head` is pointing to `node(5.0)`

Then you call `boltSize.delete(value: 5.0)`

and let's look at what the function does

```
func delete(value: Double) {
        if head?.value != value {
            head?.nextNodeAddress = head?.nextNodeAddress
        }
    }
```

1. You pass the function `5.0`
2. The it compares `Head.value` != `5.0` which is `5.0 != 5.0` - false
3. So your next line of code does not run anyways and nothing gets deleted

Let's take another example, say you want to delete `8.0`

1. You pass the function `8.0`
2. The it compares `Head.value` != `5.0` which is `5.0 != 8.0` - true
3. So inside the `if` block `head?.nextNodeAddress = head?.nextNodeAddress` - Head's next node address is `Node(8.0)` and this line keeps it `Node(8.0)`
4. The function ends

So as you can see two issues:

1. There is no deletion happening
2. Your delete code does not have a loop to reach the correct node to delete as it ends after one iteration and comparison with the head

This is how I would approach the deletion and actually is similar to what you did in your display function:

```
func delete(_ value: Int)
{
    // Check if head itself has the data to be deleted
    if head?.value == value
    {
        // The new head is the node after head
        head = head?.nextNodeAddress
        
        // We can exit, nothing more to do
        return
    }
    
    // Create a temp node pointer that will iterate through
    // your linked list starting starting from the head
    var currentNode = head
    
    // Loop through the list till you reach the end
    while currentNode?.nextNodeAddress != nil
    {
        // Check if the next node has the value we want to delete
        if currentNode?.nextNodeAddress?.value == value
        {
            // Retrieve the next node
            let nextNode = currentNode?.nextNodeAddress
            
            // Assign current node's next to next node's next
            // This way, there is no link to the next node anymore
            currentNode?.nextNodeAddress = nextNode?.nextNodeAddress
            
            // The delete is complete and we can exit
            return
        }
        
        // Since the node was not found in this iteration, advance
        // the pointer
        currentNode = currentNode?.nextNodeAddress
    }
}
```

This is probably more verbose way to clarify what is going on, you can feel free to shorten it as you see fit.